# FATAL uninitialized warnings - action at a distance

Tags: perl, warnings

I recently hit a bug when `use warnings FATAL ...` pragma interprets mute warnings from elsewhere as a reason to die. Consider the following sample:

```
use strict;
# In one file: 

no warnings;
my %hash;
Foo->bar( my $temp = $hash{ +undef } ); # this lives
Foo->bar( $hash{ +undef } ); # this dies

# Elsewhere

package Foo;
use warnings FATAL => qw(uninitialized);

sub bar {
    my ($self, $param) = @_; # prefectly safe
    $param = "(undef)"
        unless defined $param; # even safer
    print "Param: $param\n"; 
}
```

Now this of course can be fixed big time using the same policy regarding warnings throughout the project. Or this can be fixed every time it occurs by ruling out undefs in specific places (see `# this lives` line).

My question is whether there is an acceptable solution for package Foo which doesn't require changing anything that calls it, and whether this is really a bug in Perl itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. You are experiencing a side-effect of a feature that prevents needless autovification of hash elements passed to subs.

---

Perl passes by reference. That means that changes to the arguments within the function will change the parameters on the outside.

```
$ perl -E'
   sub f { $_[0] = "xyz"; }
   f($x);
   say $x;
'
xyz
```

This applies to hash elements too.

```
$ perl -E'
   sub f { $_[0] = "xyz"; }
   my %h;
   f($h{x});
   say $h{x};
'
xyz
```

The sub doesn't know anything about the hash, so the hash element must be created before the sub is entered for there to be something to which to assign.

...or does it? It would be generally undesirable for `f($h{x})` to always create `$h{x}` if the element doesn't exist. As such, Perl postpones doing the hash lookup until `$_[0]` is accessed, at which point it's known whether the element needs to be vivified or not. This is why the warning is coming from within the sub.

Specifically, Perl doesn't pass `$h{x}` to the sub when you call `f($h{x})`. Instead, it passes a magical scalar that contains both a reference to `%h` and the key value (`x`). This postpones doing the hash lookup until `$_[0]` is accessed, where it's known whether `$_[0]` is used somewhere assignable or not.

- If `$_[0]` is used in a manner in which it doesn't change (i.e. if it's used as an rvalue), the hash element is looked up without vivifying it.
- If `$_[0]` is used in a manner in which it can change (i.e. if it's used as an lvalue), the hash element is vivified and returned.

```
$ perl -E'
   sub f { my $x = $_[0]; }  # $_[0] returns undef without vivifying $h{x}
   sub g { $_[0] = "xyz"; }  # $_[0] vivifies and returns $h{x}
   my %h;
   f($h{x});
   say 0+keys(%h);
   g($h{x});
   say 0+keys(%h);
'
0
1
```